# Want to convert EST to PST for given date in PHP

Tags: php

Can we change date which is in EST to PST format...like any PHP function for that

Ex `2012-11-28 08:00:00` which is EST to PST `2012-11-28 05:00:00`

I know that we can directly subtract 3 hrs from EST.
But is there any PHP in built function which support it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$time = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```